# quotient_type warning "no map function"

Tags: isabelle

When using the quotient_type command I get the following warning: "No map function defined for Example.A. This will cause problems later on".
Here is a minimal example to trigger the warning(tested with Isabelle2017).

```
theory Example
imports
Main
begin
datatype 'a A = B "'a A" | C
  (*for map: map *) (* uncommenting doesn't fix the warning*)
quotient_type 'a Q = "'a A" / "op ="
  by (rule identity_equivp)
end
```

So my questions are:
What is meant by a map function in this context (I only do know the concept of a map function in the context of functors in functional programming)?
What does it have to do with the datatype packages map functions, like one that would be generated by the commented line?
Which problems will one get later on?

Answer (score 1):

The `datatype` command does not by default register the generated map function with the quotient package because there may be more general mappers (in case there are dead type variables). You therefore must do the functor declaration manually:

```
functor map_A
   by(simp_all add: A.map_id0 A.map_comp o_def)
```

The mapper and its theorems are needed if you later want to lift definitions through the quotient type. This has been [discussed](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-isabelle-users/2015-March/msg00162.html) on the Isabelle mailing list.